# how to fix the issue of intellij while debugging another file is opening

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

while trying to debugging my code then another tab is opening and debugger debugging in that (i think it is opening internal implementation of the code)
[this image highlights at that blue line after clicking step into while trying to stepping into another line but it is opening another tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I00AR.png)

[In this image as you can see it is stepping into another tab which is String.java(i think that is inner implementation, i didn't wrote that code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJJdH.png)

Comment: You see that text saying "enter image description here"? That's an instruction to you, to enter an image description. Really, the question needs to be more than just some images anyway; describe what you're trying to do, what happened, and what you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

i posted this to answer ,that for this we have to go to **configuration editor tabs** which is at the top righ[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtP2v.png)t corner with three dots then you will see settings tab

Then go to  build,Execution,deployment in that go to debugger again in that go to stepping in that uncheck the **Always do smart step into** now you can apply the changes.